# Upload Images on Mediawiki to Single Folder

Tags: image, url, path, mediawiki

Is there a way to configure Mediawiki to upload images to the same folder rather than random subfolders of the image directory?

For example, when I upload an image, I get a path like this:
http://website.com/wiki/images/5/5b/image.jpg

Can't it just be this?:
http://website.com/wiki/images/image.jpg

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, just set [$wgHashedUploadDirectory](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgHashedUploadDirectory) to false in your LocalSettings.php file.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Question though - what does it mean when it says "This is used to avoid having too many files in one folder because some filesystems don't perform well with large numbers of files in one folder." What filesystems wouldn't perform well with this setting disabled?

Comment: It actually depends on how your disk is formatted more than the operating system. Check out http://ask-leo.com/is_there_a_limit_to_what_a_single_folder_or_directory_can_hold.html. Regardless the limits are really high so you probably aren't going to have problems on a small to medium sized wiki.

Comment: We're actually anticipating this to eventually be a rather large wiki (though I don't know if my "large" is the same as the "large" you're talking about). Our wiki is probably going to have about 30,000 articles at max, with maybe 150,000 images uploaded.

Comment: We if you have a FAT32 disk (like on Windows XP for example) you are limited to 65,534 files in a folder. If you are on 7 or NT or any variety of Windows Server, you are probably formatted with NTFS which can support 4,294,967,295 files in a folder.